# I need help for Json parsing with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, parsing, alamofire

I am a beginner programmer and I couldn't parse my json file. I can see datas in my console but I need help to parse json datas. I shared my json datas from url and I would like to parse with Alamofire. I installed PodFile with Alamofite and SwiftyJSON. I don't have any error but I need help for parse it. 
Also I created string Arrays for following datas. I will append data in arrays.

```
[
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "team" : "Liverpool",
    "players" : [
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Alisson",
        "position" : "Goal Keeper",
        "number" : "13"
      },
      {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "Salah",
        "position" : "Forward",
        "number" : "10"
      }
    ],
    "trophies" : [
      "2019 champions league",
      "2005 champions league"
    ],
    "logoUrl" : "url"
  },
  {
    "id" : 4,
    "team" : "Real Madrid",
    "players" : [
      {
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "Ramos",
        "position" : "Defender",
        "number" : "4"
      },
      {
        "id" : 6,
        "name" : "Benzema",
        "position" : "Forward",
        "number" : "9"
      }
    ],
    "trophies" : [
      "2018 champions league",
      "2017 champions league",
      "2016 champions league"
    ],
    "logoUrl" : "url"
  }
]
```

---

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

func fetchJsonData(){
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Alamofire.request(url).responseData { response in
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            do {
                let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([PageData].self, from:data)
                print(res)
            } catch  {
                print("having trouble converting it to a dictionary" , error)
            }
        }

        }
}

// this is my modal file

struct PageData: Codable { 
    let team: String
    let players: [Player]
    let trophies: [String]
    let logoUrlL: String 
}

struct Player: Codable {
    let id: Int 
    let name,position, number: String?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `responseData` for using `JSONDecoder`

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseData { response in 
    guard let data = response.data else { return } 
    do { 
        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([PageData].self, from:data)
        print(res)
    } catch  {
        print("having trouble converting it to a dictionary" , error)
    }
}
```

Also `players` and `trophies` are arrays

```
struct PageData: Codable { 
    let team: String
    let players: [Player]
    let trophies: [String]
    let logoUrlL: String 
}

struct Player: Codable {
    let id: Int 
    let name,position, number, type, quantity: String?
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but Having trouble converting it to a dictionary. I couldn't see any data in console bro

Comment: re-copy the structs from answer and try

Comment: Man its my mistake sorry for type and qualtity. Its my personal mistake sorry. I edit it. players will have just name position an number string :(   sorry again

Comment: edit still make it an array with `[{}]` ?? do you need it `{}` as 1 item dictionary ??

Comment: I can see [{}] with my code on console. and I will list team informations with tableview. I couldn't parse it my friend :/

Comment: replaced code as in answer ? also do you have error in `print("having trouble converting it to a dictionary" , error)`

Comment: Yes I replace the codes but still catch block is active.
print("having trouble converting it to a dictionary" , error)
Error is : 
valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 7", intValue: 7), CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: ok make `name` optional so re-copy `struct Player: Codable {` and try

Comment: `let name,position, number, type, quantity: String?`  and try also re-copy  if there any error

Comment: man I made a mistake when I write json part. There are not type and quantity. just name position and number sting values. 
Error is : having trouble converting it to a dictionary valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 7", intValue: 7), CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: try to make `logoUrlL` optional also ?

Comment: I would like to an extra thing man! Could you help me to append teams, player names and trophies in string arrays?
I am appreciate you btw.

Comment: add another separate question of the problem you're facing and share it's link here

Comment: Sh_Khan

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758760/how-can-i-append-json-values-in-sting-arrays

Comment: @CagkanT. do you mean that  you have a local json in your  bundle that you need  to add it's content to the array from the api call ???

Comment: no. I have a url and getting informations from a service. and I need to list in a tableview teams players and trophies. I am beginner man :) my friend prepared a service for me and I have http link. I don't know how to parse values. I need to list teams, players and trophies.

Comment: Do you need  to merge all teams in an array and all players in an array same for trophies ?

Comment: yes. after that i will use that arrays in tableview cell. 
teams[indexPath.row] i will use a label for list teams, a label for players and textview

Comment: each cell represents a team the label of the player will show all players names say separated with a coma ?

Comment: I need to list following items in tableview. I will list teams in a label. I will list players in another label I will list trophies in a textview all of them will be in a tableview cell.
My table view cell row height is 500 px. there will be 2 labels. first label will list to team names. second label will list to player names and a textview will list trophies.