# How can I append Json values in sting arrays?

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, swift5

I am parsing Json with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. I can see all json data from url. Everything is clear in my console but I need to append some values in string arrays. As you can see json values. I create 3 string arrays. I need to append to arrays teams, player names and trophies. I will list team and player name in tableview. I need help to append values in arrays

// json values in console

```
[
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "team" : "Liverpool",
    "players" : [
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Alisson",
        "position" : "Goal Keeper",
        "number" : "13"
      },
      {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "Salah",
        "position" : "Forward",
        "number" : "10"
      }
    ],
    "trophies" : [
      "2019 champions league",
      "2005 champions league"
    ],
    "logoUrl" : "url"
  },
  {
    "id" : 4,
    "team" : "Real Madrid",
    "players" : [
      {
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "Ramos",
        "position" : "Defender",
        "number" : "4"
      },
      {
        "id" : 6,
        "name" : "Benzema",
        "position" : "Forward",
        "number" : "9"
      }
    ],
    "trophies" : [
      "2018 champions league",
      "2017 champions league",
      "2016 champions league"
    ],
    "logoUrl" : "url"
  }
]
```

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

var team = [String]()
var playerName = [String]()
var trophies = [String]()

func fetchJsonData(){
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Alamofire.request(url).responseData { response in
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            do {
                let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([PageData].self, from:data)
                print(res)
            } catch  {
                print("having trouble converting it to a dictionary" , error)
            }
        }

        }
}

// this is my modal file

struct PageData: Codable { 
    let team: String?
    let players: [Player]
    let trophies: [String]
    let logoUrlL: String?
}

struct Player: Codable {
    let id: Int 
    let name,position, number: String?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make `res` mutable

```
var res = try JSONDecoder().decode([PageData].self, from:data)
```

Add a player to Liverpool

```
if let index = res.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "Liverpool"}) {
   res[index].players.append(Player(id: 7, name: "Virgil van Dijk", position: "Defender", number: "4"))
}
```

Add a trophy to Real Madrid

```
if let index = res.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "Real Madrid"}) {
   res[index].trophies.append("None in 2019")
}
```

Add a team

```
res.append(PageData(team: "Paris Saint-Germain", 
                    players: [Player(id: 8, name: "Neymar Jr.", position: "Forward", number: "10")], 
                    trophies: ["Ligue 1 2019"]))
```

And according to your code you don't use `SwiftyJSON`

Comment: I get informations from a url. I need to list following items in tableview.
I will list teams in a label.
I will list players in another label
I will list trophies in a textview
all of them will be in a tableview cell.

Comment: The structs are pretty straightforward. Just get the information you need directly from the struct members.

Comment: really I need help. I have 3 string arrays. team, playerName and trophies.
I need to append that informations in arrays. Could you help me about this. I am beginner and I need to help for this :/

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does *I need to append that informations in arrays* mean? My answer describes how to add information to the `res` array. And why do you need multiple arrays? You got the structs.

Comment: @vadian you probably just need to convert the array back to json (encode it)

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, that's just one additional line. But I have no idea what the OP is going to accomplish. Maybe even I misunderstood the question completely

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

1- Declare an array like

```
var arr = [PageData]()
```

2- Assign here and reload

```
arr = try JSONDecoder().decode([PageData].self, from:data)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

3- Set dataSource and delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CellName
    let item = arr[indexPath.row]
    cell.teamlbl.text = item.team
    cell.playerslbl.text = item.players.map{ $0.name}.joined(separator:"-")
    cell.trophieslbl.text = item.trophies.joined(separator:"-")
    return cell
}
```

---

**Edit:**

```
  var teams = [String]()
  var players = [Player]()
  var trophies = [String]()


  arr = try JSONDecoder().decode([PageData].self, from:data)
  self.teams = arr.compactMap { $0.team }
  self.players = arr.flatMap { $0.players }.compactMap { $0.name }
  self.trophies = arr.flatMap { $0.trophies } 
  self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: when I will click to tableview segue will send all informations to detail view. could you chow me please how to append values in arrays like my code?

Comment: it works thank you but that's not what i need my friend. I need to send datas to another view with segue. I need append values to 3 different arrays.
I need to use code like this
cell.lblTeam.text = team[indexPath.row]

Comment: see edit if you do that your 3 arrays will be of different size and it'll not fit for a table dataSource `arr[indexPath.row].team` is the same thing and it encapsulates all players/trophies related to that item